# unable to upload file through storage

Tags: pdf-generation, azure-storage

I am following this [document](https://pdfkit.org/) for pdfkit. i have installed and created into pdf but when I attempted to upload my created files to azure blob storage, it returns an error.

An error message appears using JavaScript.

```java
const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.fontSize(27).text("test", 100, 100);
doc.end();

const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(
      doc,
      Buffer.byteLength(doc)
    );
```

Pdfkit is a medium active ecosystem, and I am using latest version of pdfkit only.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error message you are getting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce in my environment i am getting the result successfully. To upload a PDF file, please use the code provided below.

```java
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');
const blobName = "imran.pdf";
const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(blobName));
doc.fontSize(27).text("test", 100, 100);
doc.end();

const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(blobName);
```

[image]